# Jackson XmlMaaper fails to decode null Double

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml, xmlmapper

I’m experiencing a strange Jackson issue. The XmlMapper could not deserialize what is serialized by itself.
And the error only occurs when there’re nulls in the Double array. A sample test case to reproduce the issue is below:

```
@Test
public void testDerSer(){
    Double[] testDouble = new Double[]{null, null, null, 3.0d, 34.5d};
    try {
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        byte[] bytes = xmlMapper.writeValueAsBytes(testDouble);
        System.out.println(new String(bytes));
        Double[] doubles = xmlMapper.readValue(bytes, Double[].class);
        System.out.println(doubles);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The serialized payload looks like this:

```
<Doubles><item/><item/><item/><item>3.0</item><item>34.5</item></Doubles>
```

And the error is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Double` out of START_OBJECT token
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `Double[]` with `ArrayList` you get result

```
xmlMapper.readValue(bytes, ArrayList.class)
```

then you get

```
[{}, {}, {}, 3.0, 34.5]
```